# How to use svg sprite and symbol in twig?

Tags: symfony, svg, twig

I created svg sprites and I want to use it in my applicaton as 
Example in footer.twig:

```
{{ asset("images/svg/sprites.svg") }}
<div>
    <symbol id="icon-down" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M20.203 10.905h-1.899a.379.379 0 0 0-.284.13l-5.13 5.913V3.75a.188.188 0 0 0-.188-.188h-1.406a.188.188 0 0 0-.187.188v13.198l-5.13-5.914a.372.372 0 0 0-.284-.129H3.796c-.16 0-.246.19-.14.31l7.778 8.965a.75.75 0 0 0 1.133 0l7.776-8.965a.187.187 0 0 0-.14-.31z" fill="#000"></path>
    </symbol>
</div>
```

but it does not work. When I use same svg in image tag it shows. Any help?

Comment: 1. You need to put the symbol in a svg element. 2. You need to use (`<use xlink:href="#icon-down" />`) the symbol inside an svg element.

Comment: thx. it is a one step closer to solution. Now if I put svg as you said, <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-down" /> </svg>
it still does not show if I try to import it like {{ asset("images/svg/sprites.svg") }}, but if I put <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute"><symbol id="icon-down" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d....   </symbol> it works